# Change a parameter of a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a `Pipeline` that I've trained and saved using `pickle`. It contains the following steps:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing': Preprocessor()),
('my_transformer': my_transformer()), 
('model': XGBClassifier())
])
```

I want to log some informations when `my_transformer()` is executed, but only when I predict probabilities, i.e when I run `pipeline.predict_proba()`. I do not want the logging line to be executed when I run `pipeline.predict()`.

Here is what `my_transformer()` looks like this:

```
class my_transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, flag_log=False):
    self.flag_log = flag_log

  def transform(self, features):
    #apply transformations
    if self.flag_log:
      logger.info("log probabilities")
```

What I want to do is to modify the value of `flag_log` based on if I want to log information or not. Basically, I want to have something like this:

```
pipeline.set_params(my_transformer__flag_log=True)
probabilities = pipeline.predict_proba(features)
pipeline.set_params(my_transformer__flag_log=False)
predictions = pipeline.predict(features)
```

I tried the code above, but It does not work, the value of `flag_log` does not change.
Is there some other solution to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the value of flag_log simply run:

```
pipeline.set_params(my_transformer__flag_log=False)
```

That should work and works for me. Otherwise if you are sure, that it does not work that way, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, so that others can reproduce your issue (I'll look into it and update my answer then).